# IOHIDSystem cursor update overdue. Resending

Tags: macos

I have spent weeks attempting to address a significant, core issue with my MacPro.  During normal use, the mouse, keyboard and general functionality halts for a few seconds and my Console displays the following error:

> > kernel[0]: IOHIDSystem cursor update overdue. Resending.

This issue now occurs almost once a minute, during which time mouse and keyboard input halts (drops). General functionality locks up for about 1-3 seconds.

I have a MacPro (2 x 2.8 Quad-Core Xeon) with:

- 14GB of DDR2 memory
- ATI Radeon HD 5770 (1024MB)
- Mac OSX 10.8.2

Here are some things I've read online and tried to address:

- I only use a wired, USB mouse and keyboard plugged directly into the MacPro (possible issues with Bluetooth mouse/keyboard)
- I have migrated the OS to different hard drives (possible issues with a failing drive).  Both SATA and SSD drives.
- I have reset PRAM
- Removed second monitor
- I have removed all other USB devices
- Uninstalled Adobe Flash
- Problem exists even after restart when not running any additional applications outside of Finder
- Fresh installation of Mac OS X

This issue has existed with previous versions of Mac OSX (10.7 through present), but has gotten progressively worse.

I have Googled extensively and tried all of the various fixes (listed above), to no avail.  Has anyone encountered this issue with their MacPro and located a solution?

Comment: me too - but this question really belongs on superuser or thinkdifferent. Does reboot solve it for you?

Comment: I've asked a related question at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88211/cursor-stuttering-iohidsystem-cursor-update-overdue-resending